# Difficulty shifting into first gear on 1995 VW Golf

Tags: transmission, vw, shifting

It has become very difficult to shift into 1st gear on my 1995 VW Golf.  Pushing the shifter fully left and then forward now puts the transmission into 3rd.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem in my '86 Jetta.  The problem was a missing/broken bushing, which required dropping the tailpipe to fix.  I instead solved the problem with some tin snips and a tin can, by creating my own "bushing" under the shifter boot.  I don't know how similar the 95 Golf is to the 86 Jetta shifter, though, but it sounds like the same fundamental problem.

Comment: I would post pictures if I could, but that car is 1500 miles from me at the moment.

Comment: (If someone can confirm that these two cars have similar shifter designs, I could have my brother photograph my Jetta, and form an actual answer here from my ghetto DIY fix)

Answer (score 3):

As Flimzy's comment suggests, many transverse-engined FWD cars, including Volkswagens, use a series of ball-joints with plastic bushes in their gear linkages, and these can fail over time.

I expect you will find two sets of linkages - one for the side-to-side movement of the gearstick, and one for the fore-and-aft. I suspect it will be the former that has failed - do you get fifth when you try to engage third and fourth instead of second?

This is a common failnig on Peugeots from the late 80s and early 90s, we used to fix it by looping zip-ties around each bar of the linkage just before the ball-joint to tie them together and stop the ball-joints popping apart.

Another, less likely, possibility is a failed gearbox mount. This would cause the gearbox to drop slightly and thus throw the linkages out of alignment. I suspect you'd see other symptoms if that was the case however!

Comment: I have replaced more than one plastic "socket" on A1 and A2 VWs.  They wear out, they crack, they break in the cold.